# How to customise GNOME Terminal's context menu?

Tags: gnome-terminal, customization, context-menu

I want to customize the context menu of my terminal (`gnome-terminal`), and add some custom-made plugins shortcuts. How can I customize this?

[image: gnome-terminal context menu]

(I had to take picture from phone because I couldn't take a screenshot showing the context menu.)

I'm using Ubuntu 21.10. Here is the output of `lsb_release -a`:

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 21.10
Release:        21.10
Codename:       impish
```

Answer (score 1):

You are showing a picture of the default terminal emulator in Ubuntu, `gnome-terminal`. This terminal emulator (and many others, I believe) do not expose a user interface to change the right-click context menu. Your only option, but that is for many users not accessible, would be to edit source code and compile your custom version of the terminal emulator.